# Use .prev() to show previous column

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an HTML table where I basically have columns broken up into sets of 3.  The first 2 columns carry the css display:none; to hide them, the 3rd column is visible. (3rd columns made yellow in snippet to make things visually easier to understand)  My goal is that when I mouseover any td in the 3rd column, the first 2 columns appear.  My thought was to use

```
        $("td").hover(function(){
            $(this).prev().removeClass('hidetd');
        });
```

to make the previous column visible again, but it only refers to the previous td so this does not work.

**Is there anything in jQuery that I could use that would select the whole column instead of just that td?**  Ive done a good bit of searching online without any luck.

In the snippet below I purposely did not include the .hidetd css because I thought it would be easier to understand when seeing them.  Adding a simple

```
.hidetd{
display:none;
```

}

in the CSS section will make those columns disappear.  I am also aware that the colspan="3" will need to be removed and only added to the column when it is moused over.  Hopefully the below snippet is easy to understand though.

```css
table,th, td {
  
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
        
}

.yellowbr {
  background-color:yellow;  
}
```

```html
<table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Item #</th>
                    <th colspan='3'>100017</th>
                    <th colspan='3'>100018</th>
                    <th colspan='3'>100019</th>
                    <th colspan='3'>100020</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Component</th>
                    <th colspan='3'><u>Potato chips</u></th>
                    <th colspan='3'><u>butterfingers</u></th>
                    <th colspan='3'><u>Flat Pretzels</u></th>
                    <th colspan='3'><u>Milk Chocolate</u></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>2016-01-03</th>
                    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
                    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
                    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
                    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
                    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
                    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
                    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
                    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
                    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
                    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
                    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
                    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>2016-01-04</th>
                    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
                    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
                    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
                    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
                    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
                    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
                    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
                    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
                    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
                    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
                    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
                    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>2016-01-05</th>
                    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
                    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
                    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
                    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
                    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
                    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
                    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
                    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
                    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
                    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
                    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
                    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>2016-01-06</th>
                    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
                    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
                    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
                    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
                    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
                    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
                    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
                    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
                    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
                    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
                    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
                    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>2016-01-07</th>
                    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
                    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
                    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
                    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
                    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
                    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
                    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
                    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
                    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
                    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
                    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
                    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `prevAll()` and then `slice` to get just the two previous items, like this:

> ```
> $('.yellowbr').hover(function() {
>   $(this).prevAll().slice(0, 2).toggleClass('light')
> })
> ```

```js
$('.yellowbr').hover(function() {
  $(this).prevAll().slice(0, 2).toggleClass('light')
})
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.yellowbr {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.light {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Item #</th>
    <th colspan='3'>100017</th>
    <th colspan='3'>100018</th>
    <th colspan='3'>100019</th>
    <th colspan='3'>100020</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Component</th>
    <th colspan='3'><u>Potato chips</u>
    </th>
    <th colspan='3'><u>butterfingers</u>
    </th>
    <th colspan='3'><u>Flat Pretzels</u>
    </th>
    <th colspan='3'><u>Milk Chocolate</u>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2016-01-03</th>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2016-01-04</th>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2016-01-05</th>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2016-01-06</th>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2016-01-07</th>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</div>
```

---

To select the entire column you can use `index` as reference something like this:

```js
$('.yellowbr').hover(function() {
  var sel = $(this).index();
  $('tr').each(function(){
    $('td',this).slice(sel-3,sel-1).toggleClass('light')
  })
})
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.yellowbr {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.light {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Item #</th>
    <th colspan='3'>100017</th>
    <th colspan='3'>100018</th>
    <th colspan='3'>100019</th>
    <th colspan='3'>100020</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Component</th>
    <th colspan='3'><u>Potato chips</u>
    </th>
    <th colspan='3'><u>butterfingers</u>
    </th>
    <th colspan='3'><u>Flat Pretzels</u>
    </th>
    <th colspan='3'><u>Milk Chocolate</u>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2016-01-03</th>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2016-01-04</th>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2016-01-05</th>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2016-01-06</th>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2016-01-07</th>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</div>
```

Comment: This is definitely very helpful to know! But how could I make this select the full columns instead of just the 2 previous td?  Keep in mind my plans are to have these rows hidden and then reappear when that mouse over happens, which is why Im asking about the whole column

Comment: @Brandon what you mean by the full columns ? you mean all tds inside any tr ?

Comment: See how I highlighted every 3rd full column in yellow? anytime the mouse is anywhere inside of that yellow, I want the 2 full columns before that to be selected.

Comment: That works great!  If you dont mind me asking, I am still very new to jQuery and Id love to understand why this works also.  Looking at your jQuery line, the first line just says this is when anything with the class yellowbr is hovered.  The second line is calling for the index of the td that is beind hovered.  The 3rd line I get confused though because I thought tr was basically the container for the row?  Im not really following what is going on inside of that function either.  Thank you so much for your help though!

Comment: @Brandon that third line goes trough each tr element not just the parent container and then inside each tr target the range of `td` elements we need to modify